# Is there an event for middle mouse down in dart?

Tags: dart

How do I perform an action on middle mouse button (the scroll wheel being clicked) down?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answered my own question.

```
parentNode.onMouseDown.listen((MouseEvent e) {
    if (e.button == 1) {
        //do something
    }
}
```